# How to edit manifest to create test deployment for Google Sheets add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Years ago, I created an add-on for Google Sheets that I was able to deploy within my college domain. Specifically, I was able to access it on spreadsheets through the `Extensions` menu. It recently stopped working, with a message about the developer not having accepted the Marketplace terms of service. I am trying to create a test deployment so I can again use it.

When in the (new) Apps Script editor, I select `Deploy` > `Test Deployments`. When I try creating a Google Workspace Add-on, I get this error message:

> To test deployment as Add-on, update the manifest file with Add-on details. [Learn more](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview) about Add-ons.

I am not able to find any helpful information at the linked page about how to update the manifest file. This is the current `appsscript.json` file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "serviceId": "drive",
        "version": "v2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "MYSELF"
  }
}
```

How am I supposed to update the file so I can make a test deployment?

The project includes 3 files:

- `appsscript.json`
- `sidebar.html`
- `Code.gs`

The code includes `onInstall()` and `onOpen()` methods. It uses the Drive v2 API.

I know that the code is all right, because I am able to paste it into the Apps Script editor in spreadsheets and run it from there. I'd rather not have to copy and paste it into sheets.

Comment: I would suggest checking first the message about the Marketplace terms of service as you may have created an add on that may require an update. You may as well check this documentation about updating [manifests for add ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons)

Comment: Thank you, @GabrielCarballo. After changing my manifest, I got the terms of service error again. I can't figure out where to accept the terms of service. I created a developer profile but never got shown TOS.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo I created a separate question about accepting the terms. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71534436/631051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Manifest for a sheets addon

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "serviceId": "drive",
        "version": "v2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "webapp": {
    "executeAs": "USER_DEPLOYING",
    "access": "MYSELF"
  },
  "sheets": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onEditorsHomepage"
      },
      "onFileScopeGrantedTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onFileScopeGrantedEditors"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. After you helped me, I found this page. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests