# How do I accept the terms and conditions of the Google Workspace Marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-developer-tools, google-workspace-add-ons

I wrote an Apps Script add-on for spreadsheets and [created a test deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71532351/631051). When I try installing the add-on in a spreadsheet, I got this message:

> The developer of this add-on has not accepted the terms and conditions of the Google Workspace Marketplace. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/docs?p=GSM_migration)

The referenced page did not include any useful information. I have created a developer profile but was never prompted to accept the terms and conditions. I looked on my dashboard but didn't see anything there either.

How do I accept the terms and conditions of the Google Workspace Marketplace? In case it matters, this is within an .edu domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look in your GCP platform the projects created for this Add on and from there you need to enable the Marketplace SDK:

[image]

This should accept the Terms and conditions as stated here:

[image]